# Are there any automocking libraries in the Java world?

Tags: mocking

I'm looking for something similar to the structuremap or eleution automocking containers in the .NET world

Comment: Maybe if you explained what that meant - there aren't many people here that do both .net and java.

Comment: Fair enough: An automocking container leverages an IoC container to create mocks. A brief description of (I think) the first one is here: http://blog.eleutian.com/CommentView,guid,762249da-e25a-4503-8f20-c6d59b1a69bc.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for Java there is the [Unitils Mock](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial.html#Testing_with_mock_objects) library, which provides `@TestedObject` and `@InjectInto...` annotations for automatic injection of declarative mocks into tested objects.

Another option is [JMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit), but it currently does not automatically inject its mocks into tested objects. OTOH, it does create mock objects declaratively, assigning them to instance fields or passing them as test method arguments; so, there is no "createMock" method.

The use of DI is important for mocking APIs such as Unitils Mock, EasyMock, jMock, and Mockito, because they always require mock instances to be passed to code under test. With JMockit, though, DI can be used just the same, but is unnecessary since instances created internally by code under test will get mocked transparently.

Answer (score 0):

For Guice there is http://jukito.org